# Is it possible to addtoBackStack(null) in PagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have a Pager Adapter to load server images as like below:

```
class ImagePagerAdapter(var imageList: List<ProductImageModel>, var fragmentManager: FragmentManager) :
    FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {

        val fragment = ImagePagerFragment()
        fragment.arguments = Bundle().apply {
            putString(PAGER_IMAGE_URL, imageList[position].image)
        }
        return fragment
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return imageList.size
    }
}
```

I want to know any option to addtoBackStack(null) while creating a new Fragment inside the pagerAdapter.

The current code, automatically adding the fragments to the backstack. So it's making a huge issue while the user presses the back button.  I have added another logic to filter the fragments in the back press.

Comment: This sounds like it would not behave as you expect.

Comment: My requirement is to exclude the Pager fragments from Backstack : supportFragmentManager.fragments[supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount - 1]

Comment: What do you mean? I don't think you should want to add the fragments inside a PagerAdapter to a backstack. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?